# Как убрать текстовые узлы между элементами списка ul

Tags: html, html5

Ну собсна есть список. И как я понял эти узлы появляются из-за переноса строк. Как их можно убрать не портя сильно изначальный код верстки? Прост если убрать все переносы то будет не очень красиво. А так верстка немного съезжает и между элементами образуется пустое место. На картинке само пусто место а ниже код.

```html
<nav class="upper">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Продукты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Информация</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Как доехать</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стили добавьте к вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Недавно тоже искал ответ на такой вопрос и нашёл интересный способ - использовать комментарии между элементами, выглядеть это будет так:

```
...<!--
--><li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li>
...
```

Таким образом в html считается, что всё "с новой строки" в строчку.